# Domain service class Template problem

Tags: silverlight

Can you tell me how to add domain service class template as it is missing from the web part.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .Svc file and in the cs file implement the iDomainContext that will resolve your issue

making WCFService work as Domain Service.